# Cambiar visualización de columnas de una tabla html

Tags: html, css, html-tabla

He estado haciendo un index de registro de datos para un proyecto de embarques en php y html; no he usado mucho css porque aun no lo comprendo muy bien.

El problema lo tengo al visualizar los datos en una tabla html: cuando las columnas contienen datos con texto largo, el texto se 'divide' en varias líneas. Por ejemplo:

[image: formato tabla]

Cómo puedo hacer para que mi tabla no 'acorte' el tamaño de las columnas? No hay problema si tengo que tener una barra de dezplazamiento horizontal para ver los datos; pero sí quiero que la columna pueda utilizar todo el tamaño que necesite.

Comment: Comparte el html para que te podamos ayudar con el diseño

Comment: Puedes intentar con un framework llamado Bootstrap, tiene un componente llamado `tables` y puede servirte para resolver tu pregunta. [Link de la documentacion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/)

Comment: Kevin Delva claro amigo deja mando la imagen

Comment: @KevinDelva no me peromite insertar mas imagenes, soy nuevo en esta pagina no se de que otra forma te lo podria mandar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probablemente lo que necesitas es la propiedad [no-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) de `whitespace`

Podrías aplicarla así:

```
.mitabla th, .mitabla td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<style>
.mitabla td, .mitabla th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<table class="mitabla">
  <td>Lorem fistrum no puedor torpedo torpedo te voy a borrar el cerito qué dise usteer. Condemor me cago en tus muelas diodeno tiene musho peligro va usté muy cargadoo papaar papaar de la pradera no te digo trigo por no llamarte Rodrigor. No te digo trigo por no llamarte Rodrigor apetecan pupita diodenoo de la pradera por la gloria de mi madre ese que llega. Sexuarl no te digo trigo por no llamarte Rodrigor se calle ustée fistro por la gloria de mi madre tiene musho peligro benemeritaar condemor te va a hasé pupitaa sexuarl. Diodenoo fistro va usté muy cargadoo me cago en tus muelas benemeritaar ese pedazo de a gramenawer se calle ustée te voy a borrar el cerito está la cosa muy malar. La caidita papaar papaar jarl jarl la caidita qué dise usteer mamaar condemor amatomaa caballo blanco caballo negroorl. Va usté muy cargadoo caballo blanco caballo negroorl qué dise usteer condemor a wan caballo blanco caballo negroorl jarl. Ese hombree sexuarl qué dise usteer qué dise usteer benemeritaar diodenoo por la gloria de mi madre ese hombree torpedo benemeritaar se calle ustée. </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias Crack en cuanto tenga tiempo lo implementare, de antemano agradesco tu tiempo en ayudarme, espero que con esto se solucione

Comment: eres un verdadero crack amigo, me funciono a la perfeccion, como le hago para calificarte en este foro, me imagino que te dan algun puntaje por resolver dudas o no se, es la primera vez que me suscribo a un foro, en fin muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra que te funcionara. Si una respuesta resuleve tu problema, puedes marcarla como "aceptada". Por otra parte, si te resultó util, puedes "votarla" con la flecha hacia arriba.